# Angular error: when assign value to empty string[] get Error Type (string | undefined)[] is not assignable to Type String

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am doing an Angular App.
I have a problem when I want to assign a value to an empty array

I am using

```
node 12.18.4
npm 6.14.8
```

I wrote a typescript.ts like this

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Product } from "./product.model";
import { StaticDataSource } from "./static.datasource";

@Injectable()
export class ProductRepository {

    private categories: string[] = [];

    constructor(private dataSource: StaticDataSource) {
 dataSource.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
        ().subscribe(data => {
            this.categories = data.map(p => p.category)
                .filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) == index).sort();
        });
    }   
}
```

Here is the definition of Products and GetProducts()

```
@Injectable()
export class StaticDataSource {
    private products: Product[] = [
        new Product(1, "Product 1", "Category 1", "Product 1 (Category 1)", 100),
        new Product(2, "Product 2", "Category 1", "Product 2 (Category 1)", 100),
    ];

    getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
        return from([this.products]);
    }
```

the definition of `Products` is

```
export class Product {

    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public name?: string,
        public category?: string,
        public description?: string,
        public price?: number) { }
}
```

I have compilation errors

```
 Error:    
Type (string | undefined)[] is not assignable to Type String. On line

      this.categories = data.map(p => p.category)
      .filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) == index).sort();
```

the problem is in the definition of `Products`
where in the constructor all the properties can be null... If I  remove `?` in the constructor. It works fine.

How can I write this query

```
this.categories = data.map(p => p.category)
                    .filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) == index).sort();
```

where data can be null?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check that every element of the array 'data' has the key 'category', and value of all category is not undefined.

Example:
If

```
data =  [{category:'a'},{categories:'b'},{category:'c'}];
```

then

```
data.map(p => p.category)
  .filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) == index).sort();
```

gives:

```
["a", "c", undefined]
```

which is of type

```
Type (string | undefined)[]
```

Solution:
Modify your code to:

```
data.map(p => p.category)
  .filter((c, index, array) => c && array.indexOf(c) == index).sort();
```

In your filter, just check if current element value is valid or not.

Comment: HI, just added where is the problem. data can be null. But adding c && to the query still have the same problem, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `().subscribe` is not a valid subscription to an observable but I'm guessing you added that here as an example.

You're getting the error because what you get in your subscription can be null/undefined (you're running in strict mode which is great but it can confuse someone new to Angular). You either check inside the subscription if the data exists before you assign it to your property, either use the RxJS `filter` operator.

```js
myObservable$.pipe(filter(data => !!data)).subscribe(data => {
  this.categories = data!.map(p => p.category)
      .filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) == index).sort();
})
```

Tips: Use ngOnInit() to initialize your data instead of the constructor. Also, for increasing the performance use the async pipe if possible instead of manually subscribing in the controller.

Comment: Just added complete code... I was missing something as you say... I just copied the example of a book. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue may arise as result of both declaration and initialization at the same time, you can try this:

```
private categories: string[];
```

Comment: HI ,it this case I have an error on the initialized "Property categories has not initializer nad is not definitely assigned in the constructor.". Thanks